# RegEx or Pygrok Pattern match

Tags: python, regex, grok

I have text like this

Example:
"visa code: **ab c** master number: **efg** discover: **i j k**"

**Output should be like this:
abc, efg, ijk**

Is there a way, I can use Grok pattern match or Reg EX to get 3 characters after the ":" (not considering space) ?

Comment: There is, but you will need to give more detail. Can you give an example of input and what you want the resulting match to be?

Answer (score -1):

You can start with this:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r"\b((?:\w\s*){2}\w)\b")
>>> re.findall(p, "visa code: ab c master number: efg discover: i j k")
['ab c', 'efg', 'i j k']
```

But you have more work to do. For example, nobody can guess what you mean - exactly - by "characters".

Beyond that, pattern matching systems match strings, but do not convert them. You'll have to remove spaces you don't want via some other means (which should be easy).